# Setting a new SKScenes Background will not work

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I cannot seem to set the background color of a new SKScene I have created:

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.black

}
```

No matter what I change it just remains a grey background. This is how I'm loading the new SKScene(inside of touches began):

```
if (label).contains(location) {

  let newScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameLoaded")
  self.view?.presentScene(newScene)

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The way you set the background color should work, so there must be another problem with your project. Try doing additional configuration on your scene, like `scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill` and `scene.size = view.bounds.size`. If you still have problems, you might create a new SpriteKit template project and review how the scene is presented successfully in that project.